# Composer v0.16.5 error - admin has not been registered

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have just updated to composer v0.16.5 and when I try to set up my network as I would normally I keep getting an error:

> Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business
>   network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The
>   current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier
>   'c2610678f95fe3542e71e0728d114ca724d4c255e63fc2d6c4371942317f6608',
>   has not been registered

This usually means that the admin credentials are stored from another time but I cant seem to get rid of them.

I tried removing all the docker containers, images, fabric-tools, local state and starting again from scratch but I keep getting the same error.

Has something changed from v0.16.3 to v0.16.5?

These are the commands I carry out:

Create my .bna file:

```
composer archive create --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./dist/block-aviation-network.bna
```

Deploy the network:

```
composer runtime install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --businessNetworkName block-aviation-network
composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -A admin -S adminpw -a ./dist/block-aviation-network.bna -f networkadmin.card
composer card import -f networkadmin.card
```

Then to setup mongoDb instance that will store all blockchain identities:

```
docker run -d --name mongo --network composer_default -p 172.20.10.2:27017:27017 mongo
```

Initialise the enviroment variables store in envars.txt by running the following command:

```
source envvars.txt
```

Build the docker image for the composer rest server

```
docker build -t myorg/my-composer-rest-server .
```

setup composer REST server:

```
docker run \
    -d \
    -e COMPOSER_CARD=${COMPOSER_CARD} \
    -e COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=${COMPOSER_NAMESPACES} \
    -e COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION=${COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION} \
    -e COMPOSER_MULTIUSER=${COMPOSER_MULTIUSER} \
    -e COMPOSER_PROVIDERS="${COMPOSER_PROVIDERS}" \
    -e COMPOSER_DATASOURCES="${COMPOSER_DATASOURCES}" \
    -v ~/.composer:/home/composer/.composer \
    --name rest \
    --network composer_default \
    -p 172.20.10.2:3000:3000 \
    myorg/my-composer-rest-server
```

If I look at `docker logs rest` I see the output I should: `Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer`

I then authenticate my rest sever by navigating to /auth/github. It returns me to my REST server as expected.

I then export my networkadmin.card using the command:

```
composer card export -f networkadmin.card -n admin@block-aviation-network
```

I then import the exported card into theREST server and try a GET /system/ping/

But I get the error as outlined above.

If I run the following command from my terminal:

```
composer transaction submit --card admin@block-aviation-network -d '{"$class":"org.blockaviation.OurSetupDemo"}'
```

and then issue an identity to a participant in the network:

```
composer identity issue --card admin@block-aviation-network --file lessor.card --newUserId lessor --participantId 'resource:org.blockaviation.Lessor#lessor@gmail.com'
```

if I then export the lessor.card and set it to the default card in my rest server I can successfully carry out a GET /system/ping so it seems that its only for the networkadmin.card?

Is anyone experiencing the same problem with composer v0.16.5 or am I doing something incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably hitting this issue https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3413

The only changes between 0.16.3 to 0.16.5 were HSM support, so unless you have a need for HSM support then I would suggest not upgrading to 0.16.4 or 0.16.5.